# How to open new page from view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i have. view and  viewmodel in same project.i was opennig a new page on button click on code behind like this

```
private void button_click(object sender, routedeventargs e)
{
    var dashboardwindow = new dashboard();
    this.navigationservice.navigate(new uri("../view/dashboard.xaml", urikind.relative));
}
```

now i have added user authentication on this buton click using MVVM.so how can i open this page from view model.?

if i used window instead of page then i can open new window simply like this

```
 Dashboard dl = new Dashboard();
            dl.Show();
```

thats workd.but i have taken pages because i need bowser type navigation in my application so.. please help .Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Open a new View from the ViewModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671336/wpf-open-a-new-view-from-the-viewmodel)

Comment: no this is not same..i have been gone though this link

Comment: i have views and view models in same project.and i dont want to open window. i want to open page from view model.so wanted to know how can i do it

Comment: What do you mean by page here? So you want to navigate to new view `dashboard.xaml` in the same window on clicking the `Button`?

Comment: yes in my application I have used one navigation window and all other pages.

Comment: if  my login page and dashboard.xaml are window then i can open simply like this also "Dashboard dl = new Dashboard();
                dl.Show();"

Comment: but i had taken pages instead of window for browsertype navigation. so dnt know how to reditect it

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216068/2819451) should help you and give you clear idea.